# How can I correctly pass an onChange event to multiple input checkboxes in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass an onChange event listener to a group of checkboxes. However, once I click on one checkbox, everything gets clicked and the conditional inline styles I set are all applied.

This is the JSX code

```
class PizzaBuilder extends Component {
  state={
    checked: false
  }
 handleCheckClick = ()=>{
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
  }
render(){
return (
 <div>
                       <img style={{display: this.state.checked?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '300', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}} src={Pepperoni} alt="pepperoni"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                       <img  style={{display: this.state.checked?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '300', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}}src={Sausage} alt="sausage"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                       <img style={{display: this.state.checked?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '300', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}} src={Pineapple} alt="pineapple"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                       <img style={{display: this.state.checked?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '300', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}} src={Peppers} alt="peppers"/>
                     </div>

<div>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni"  id="pepperoni" value = "pepperoni"
                       onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
                       checked={this.state.checked}
                       />
                       <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                       <input type="checkbox" name ="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage"
                        onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                      />
                       <label for = "sausage">Sausage</label>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                       <input type="checkbox" name ="pineapple" id="pineapple" value="pineapple"
                       onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
                       checked={this.state.checked}
                       />
                       <label for = "pineapple">Pineapple</label>
                      </div>
)
}

}
```

Comment: You're using a single boolean for `checked` so of course all checkboxes get checked at once. You need an individual `checked` variable for each checkbox. Think about it as if this was a bunch of text fields. If you're only storing a single string, and setting all the text fields' values to that same string, then of course they all show the same string value, because there is only one string.

Comment: If I made a separate checked variable, what would be the best way to go about setting a conditional style for each value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to what kingofday suggested.

```
class PizzaBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    checked: {}
  };
  handleCheckClick = (e) => {
    let map = {...this.state.checked};
    map[e.target.name] = map[e.target.name] ? !map[e.target.name] : true
    this.setState({checked: map});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        .....

        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" id="pepperoni" value="pepperoni"
                 onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckClick(e)}
                 checked={this.state.checked['pepperoni']}
          />
          <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage"
                 onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckClick(e)}
                 checked={this.state.checked['sausage']}
          />
          <label for="sausage">Sausage</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pineapple" id="pineapple" value="pineapple"
                 onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckClick(e)}
                 checked={this.state.checked['pineapple']}
          />
          <label for="pineapple">Pineapple</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

This will automatically create the state map for you and you can add as many named checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

1- assuming you have 3 check boxes:

use array for check value in state:

```
class PizzaBuilder extends Component {
  state={
    checked: [false,false,false]
  }
}
...
```

2- change input event and check value like this:

```
             <input type="checkbox" name ="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage"
                onChange={this.makeClickHandler(0)}
                checked={this.state.checked[0]}
              />
             <input type="checkbox" name ="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage"
                onChange={this.makeClickHandler(1)}
                checked={this.state.checked[1]}
              />
             <input type="checkbox" name ="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage"
                onChange={this.makeClickHandler(2)}
                checked={this.state.checked[2]}
              />
```

pay attention to index used in inputs

3- change event handler to change current state:

```
 makeClickHandler = idx => () => {
    this.setState(({checked} => {
      const current = [...checked];
      current[idx] = !current[idx];
      return {checked: current};
  }
}
```

Comment: You're mutating state. This solution is dangerous and can lead to bugs in more complex code.

Comment: Also, you don't need to bind arrow functions because arrow functions do not have a 'this' context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the state of each checkbox.

Currently, you only have the boolean `state.checked`, which is true or false, so all of them toggle.

You can either make a separate state for each of them, or an array of bools.
The array (or separate states) can then be updated from individual `handleCheckXClick` functions, or in one large function that will have to be passed a parameter to determine which checkstate to toggle.

Both individual state or an array could be used for the conditional styling, just make sure you reference the correct index.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that with only one state you need to define state for everyone like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class test extends Component {
  state = {
    Pepperoni: false,
    Sausage: false,
    Pineapple: false,
    Peppers: false,
  };

  handleCheckClick = (e) => {
    const target = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ [target]: !prevState[target] }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <img
            style={{
              display: this.state.Pepperoni ? 'block' : null,
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: '300',
              height: '400px',
              width: '400px',
              top: '375px',
              left: '130px',
            }}
            src={Pepperoni}
            alt="pepperoni"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img
            style={{
              display: this.state.Sausage ? 'block' : null,
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: '300',
              height: '400px',
              width: '400px',
              top: '375px',
              left: '130px',
            }}
            src={Sausage}
            alt="sausage"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img
            style={{
              display: this.state.Pineapple ? 'block' : null,
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: '300',
              height: '400px',
              width: '400px',
              top: '375px',
              left: '130px',
            }}
            src={Pineapple}
            alt="pineapple"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img
            style={{
              display: this.state.Peppers ? 'block' : null,
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: '300',
              height: '400px',
              width: '400px',
              top: '375px',
              left: '130px',
            }}
            src={Peppers}
            alt="peppers"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="pepperoni"
            id="pepperoni"
            value="Pepperoni"
            onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
            checked={this.state.Pepperoni}
          />
          <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="sausage"
            id="sausage"
            value="Sausage"
            onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
            checked={this.state.Sausage}
          />
          <label for="sausage">Sausage</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="pineapple"
            id="pineapple"
            value="Pineapple"
            onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
            checked={this.state.Pineapple}
          />
          <label for="pineapple">Pineapple</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="Peppers"
            id="Peppers"
            value="Peppers"
            onChange={this.handleCheckClick}
            checked={this.state.Peppers}
          />
          <label for="Peppers">Peppers</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```